# Getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)

Tags: java

I'm using the following code to save a `BufferedImage` to disk:

```
savePath = new File(path);
savePath.mkdirs();
savePath.createNewFile();
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", savePath);
```

This particular piece of code is executed off a server, and is run about 10 times for every client request. Most of the time (9 requests out of 10), it works fine, and the image is saved to disk as expected.

However, **sometimes** I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied)` on the `...ImageIO.write()` line, and the image is not saved. (The folder is still created)

What can cause the exception?

Comment: If you are using a Uinix related OS it might be an issue of permissions. Is the path of the image when it works the same as when it fails?

Comment: It's Windows. Write permissions aren't a problem. And the path is always of the form [constant_path]/[random number]/imagename.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to believe this actually works. You are creating `savePath` as a directory, by calling `mkdirs()`, and then trying to create it as a file. You need to call `savePath.getParentFile().mkdirs()` instead.

The `createNewFile()` call is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was under the impression that `mkdirs()` creates all dirs required for the file.